# Inverter using Alternator

Tags: motor, inverter

Is it possible to generate AC power by powering an alternator using a DC motor? If you think about it is much easier and better sine wave than a circuit?

Why isn't it used then? What are the drawbacks?

Also, will the loss be greater? I am estimating a 20%-30% loss (even less with better quality equipment ) but I don't really know how to calculate it nor have the equipment need for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this method (rotary converter, generically) has been used to create AC from DC and DC from AC (and AC of a different frequency or number of phases from AC). Sometimes the generator or alternator was combined with the motor in one machine, sometimes distinct [motor-generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor%E2%80%93generator) pairs were used.

A motor driven alternator will not necessarily have a beautiful textbook sine wave- the alternator design and the loading will also affect the waveform.

Obvious disadvantages include weight, cost, lifetime of the bearings, audible noise and vibration. Efficiency might be comparable to solid state in some cases so I would not list that as a disadvantage.

This is pretty much a ship that has sailed- solid-state solutions are almost always better these days. Hobbyists sometimes make rotary phase converters using scrap 3-phase motors (because you can buy them for almost nothing), but manufacturers use AC->DC->AC variable frequency converters made with IGBTs or MOSFETs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is possible, that's how it was done before it was convenient to do it with electronics.

Rough calculation of effciciency (effeciency of motor) x ( efficiency of alternator). I think the 70-80% efficiency you hope for is very optimistic.

Disadvantages: efficiency, wear and tear, frequency and voltage regulation of the produced AC.

Answer (score 1):

It existed :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_converter

They were used either for converting from AC to DC or from DC to AC.

Answer (score 0):

Inverters for cars are common place. It converts 12v (or 24v for some models) to 110v or 230v. I believe the efficiency can be as high as 90%. You can get low power inverters for as little as about 30 US dollars.

Just do a [Google search for "inverter"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inverter).

Oh wait, I misunderstood what you said.

Yes, you can do it that way. If you have a motor and an alternator, mechanically link them, power the motor and get AC from the alternator. The quality of the AC you get out will depend on the alternator. The disadvantage is it will most likely have less efficiency than an inverter such as those I mention above. Also, it will be prone to wear and tear due to moving parts. It will be heavier. It will probably be less reliable. It will be more expensive. I cannot see how you could estimate efficiency etc via calculation - especially if you don't have datasheets for both motor and alternator. You'll just need to try it and see.

Some inverters produce "modified" sine wave. It can look pretty nasty. But there are "pure" sine wave inverters which would almost certainly be better than an alternator. But either way, it depends on the alternator's design.

Another drawback of the mechanical option is the speed of the motor/alternator would have to be reliably constant at 50Hz or 60Hz. This may not be an option. If either the DC supply fluctuates, or the load on the AC, then the frequency may vary unacceptably.

Comment: There is also the issue that the alternator most likely has a multiple phase output. If you only use one of the phases to drive an AC load that is single phase the overall achievable efficiency will be even lower.